# Will Meta Superuser consider adding a "# of views" sort function to the Superuser main page?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Will Meta Superuser consider adding a "# of views" sort function to the Superuser main page?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. This is currently only valid for Beta sites, and once they leave beta the stats are removed. The easiest way to see stats for a specific non beta site is to use [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com)